# Workbook .SaveCopyAs and then make changes in the new workbook created

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working that needs to be separeted into several different file by country. In total there are around 30 files to be sent each month.

The main workbook has 5 sheets that all need to be copied to the new workbook. The catch is that one of the sheets has the data that feed to all other sheets and this data need to be splitted by the country that receives the report.

I have a code that i used to split the data before but it only copies the data sheet. I tried to adapt it so it creates a whole new workbook but it givin me an error in the last sub when trying to .SaveCopyAs

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks,

**Edit:** change the row that has the .SaveCopyAs and that sove one issue. But the macro only works for the first country because when it runs that line it opens a copy and closes the original file, thus it can go back to work with the original file. Any ideas on how to get around this? 
Many thanks

Here is the code:

````
Dim osh As Worksheet ' Original Sheet
Dim iRow As Long ' Cursors
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iFirstRow As Long ' Constant
Dim iTotalRows As Long ' Constantt
Dim iStartRow As Long ' Section delimiters
Dim iStopRow As Long
Dim sSectionName As String ' Section name (and filename)
Dim rCell As Range ' current cell
Dim sFilePath As String ' Constant
Dim iCount As Integer ' # of documents created


iCol = Application.InputBox("Enter the column number used for splitting", "Select column", 1, , , , , 1)
iRow = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting row number (to skip header)", "Select row", 2, , , , , 1)
iFirstRow = iRow

iTotalRows = osh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
sFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

If Dir(sFilePath + "\Ready to send", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir sFilePath + "\Ready to send"
End If

'Turn Off Screen Updating  Events
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do
    ' Get cell at cursor
    Set rCell = osh.Cells(iRow, iCol)
    sCell = Replace(rCell.Text, " ", "")

    If sCell = "" Or (rCell.Text = sSectionName And iStartRow <> 0) Or InStr(1, rCell.Text, "total", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        ' Skip condition met
    Else
        ' Found new section
        If iStartRow = 0 Then
            ' StartRow delimiter not set, meaning beginning a new section
            sSectionName = rCell.Text
            iStartRow = iRow
        Else
            ' StartRow delimiter set, meaning we reached the end of a section
            iStopRow = iRow - 1

            ' Pass variables to a separate sub to create and save the new worksheet
            CopyWorkbook owb, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
            iCount = iCount + 1

            ' Reset section delimiters
            iStartRow = 0
            iStopRow = 0

            ' Ready to continue loop
            iRow = iRow - 1
        End If
    End If

    ' Continue until last row is reached
    If iRow < iTotalRows Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
    Else
        ' Finished. Save the last section
        iStopRow = iRow
        CopyWorkbook owb, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
        iCount = iCount + 1

        ' Exit
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

'Turn On Screen Updating  Events
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox Str(iCount) + " documents saved in " + sFilePath


End Sub

Public Sub DeleteRows(targetSheet As Worksheet, RowFrom As Long, RowTo As Long)

Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(targetSheet.Cells(RowFrom, 1), targetSheet.Cells(RowTo, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.Select
rngRange.Delete

End Sub


Public Sub CopyWorkbook(owb As Workbook, iFirstRow As Long, iStartRow As Long, iStopRow As Long, iTotalRows As Long, sFilePath As String, sSectionName As String, fileFormat As XlFileFormat)
     Dim ash As Worksheet ' Copied sheet
     Dim awb As Workbook ' New workbook

     ' Copy book
    owb.SaveCopyAs sFilePath + "\Ready to send\" + sSectionName


     Set awb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
     Set ash = awb.Sheets("Data")

     ' Delete Rows after section
     If iTotalRows > iStopRow Then
         DeleteRows ash, iStopRow + 1, iTotalRows
     End If

     ' Delete Rows before section
     If iStartRow > iFirstRow Then
         DeleteRows ash, iFirstRow, iStartRow - 1
     End If

     ' Select left-topmost cell
     ash.Cells(1, 1).Select

     ' Clean up a few characters to prevent invalid filename
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "/", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "\", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ":", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "=", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "*", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ".", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "?", " ")

     ' Save in same format as original workbook
     awb.SaveAs


     ' Close
     awb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to pass the file format as an argument when SaveCopyAs does not take the file format as an argument of the function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas

in your line :

```
' Copy book
    owb.SaveCopyAs sFilePath + "\Ready to send\" + sSectionName, fileFormat
```

I would specify the file format in the file complete name itself as path + filename.xlsm with the desired extension (.xlsm, .xlsx etc.) as in the documentation example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\TEMP\XXXX.XLS"
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but now I have another problem, the macros does what I want only for the first country, this happens because when the .sacecopyas row runs it creates a new file and closes the original with all the data, thus the macro can't go back and keep working on it.

Comment: You can set the answer as the accepted answer if you think it is. On the other hand, for this new problem I think you close the workbook yourself in the code with: awb.Close SaveChanges:=False